# I can't run Python in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I stuck this for 1 week can not move on, could someone please help?

Solved ::: im not sure which way work. i reinstall and select for all user then i remove all "" at the end in the path and then i open cmd as user i try pip it's not work. then i did this>>>>>>>sysrecon.com/programming/…<<<<< .and then i open vs code and it's work now . not sure it will be error again or not .

Error:

[image: Error]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Python Location:

[image: Python Location]

VSCODE Location:

[image: VSCODE Location]

Comment: try in a terminal: `c:\Python39\python.exe`, this should start the python REPL (`>>>`). Exit this with `exit()`. Now try in the terminal: `python`, this should also start the REPL. If you have installed Python as Administrator only his `PATH` is set correct. The error you see means that `python` is not found on your current `PATH`

Comment: I can run c:\Python39\python.exe  but after i exit()  and try python it show :
Program 'python' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Comment: what do you get with `echo %PATH%` run as the current user, not as Administartor

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Microsoft VS Code\Microsoft VS Code\;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Microsoft VS Code\Microsoft VS Code\bin

Comment: your python related path entries end in a `\ ` and you have doubles in the `PATH` and check if the mentioned paths actually exist. Your environment images do not match this `PATH`

Comment: have you installed Python **for all Users** or only for Admin, where is this `py` command

Comment: I did for re install and select for all user now . and you mean i have to remove "\" right ?

Comment: does it work now for `python`, the backslash at the end of a path IS NOT NEEDED

Comment: it's work now im not sure which way work. i reinstall and select for all user then i remove 
all "\" at the end in the path and then i open cmd as user i try pip it's not work. then i did this>>>>>>>http://www.sysrecon.com/programming/python-pip-how-to-get-around-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using/<<<<<  .and then i open vs code and it's work now . not sure it will be error again or not .  btw much appreciate .thank you so much. now i can start coding LOL. Thanks .

Comment: yeah work now maybe it's "backslash problem" LOL

Comment: Please add code, errors, and data as **text** ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) can't be copy-&-pasted for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format are much, *much* better than code/errors/data as an image, which are somewhat better than nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please [edit] additional information into your question. While you may also put that information in comments, the primary source of information about your question is the actual content of your question, not comments. Any new information or substantive information requested by someone should be [edit]ed into the question.

Comment: sorry im new here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Let say your file is on Desktop, so in terminal use `python filename.py` it will execute the file.

side notes: try to name a file without blank spaces in between, eg: instead of using `Hello world.py` you can use `Hello_world.py` .
If you have multiple python i.e. python2.7 and python3.xx , you should use `python3 filename.py` for python3.xx and `python filename.py` to execute it using python2.7 .

Comment: PS C:\Users\Ryzen\Desktop\BasicPython> python -u "c:\Users\Ryzen\Desktop\BasicPython\HIHI.py"
Program 'python' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ python -u "c:\Users\Ryzen\Desktop\BasicPython\HIHI.py"

Comment: i ve tried to change my file's name it's not work. my friend said , may be i have something wrong with my interpreter . i can print hello world through Python Idle , and i can run hello world on CMD as admin (in user I can't run) . when i typed "py" on cmd it's show me the version of python BUT when i typed python on cmd it show me the microsoft  store window that link to python 3.8  to download.

Comment: In vscode, there is extension of python shown in screenshot, install it. After that, in terminal , navigate to the folder where your file is located and then try `python3 filename.py` . Let me know if it helped or else share what error you are getting. Don't include full path, your command should look like this `C:\Users\Ryzen\Desktop\BasicPython> python3 HIHI.py`  not the way you mentioned, and no "HIHI.py"

Comment: C:\Users\Ryzen\Desktop\BasicPython> python3 HIHI.py     or      
C:\Users\Ryzen\Desktop\BasicPython> python HIHI.py
also not work

Comment: what is the error. and you installed vscode python extension?

Comment: when  i use this it show >>>>> python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name~

Comment: Try to run this two command and tell me the output :  `python3 --version`  `python --version`

Comment: python3 --version  OUTPUT>>>python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python3 --version
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], Comman
   dNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: python --version              OUTPUT>>>Program 'python' failed to run: No application is associated with the
specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ python --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ python --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFai
   ledException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Comment: i've already installed vscode python extension.

Comment: Seems like you don't have python3, either install python3, or change your file to python 2 i.e `print "hello world!"`

Comment: Strange! i did install the latest Python 3.9 . i can check in cmd as admin i can type py and it's show Python 3.9.0

Comment: also type python in cmd(as admin) also show >>Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40)

Comment: Then maybe you should reinstall python, restart vscode after installation. Then run `py filename.py`

Comment: Follow this official document, and please upvote the answers if helpful. https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#id2

Comment: already did still the same :(

Comment: im not sure it's about that i ticked Code-runner:Run in Terminal ,if i not select Run in Terminal. it work well on OUTPUT TAB.

Comment: there should be python coming at bottom left of your vscode, if it's not there, then press  ctrl+shift+p -> Python: Select Interpreter -> select your path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe).

Follow these documents:
https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: @Snlz555 also in your variables, remove all sub-directory of `C:/ Python 39/` , just add `C:/ Python 3 9` . After that open new terminal and check. Do let know if it worked.

Comment: it's work now im not sure which way work. i reinstall and select for all user then i remove 
all "\" at the end in the path and then i open cmd as user i try pip it's not work. then i did this>>>>>>>http://www.sysrecon.com/programming/python-pip-how-to-get-around-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using/<<<<<  .and then i open vs code and it's work now . not sure it will be error again or not .  btw much appreciate .thank you so much now i can start coding LOL. eh and how to upvote ur answer everything that's very helpful .:)

Comment: PATH is the problem in windows. That's why most of developer prefer using linux and mac and setting path is much easier there compared to windows. Anyways glad it worked. Good luck for learning :)

Answer (score -1):

The commands placed after python are seen as system variables to be triggered by python, only file that end with .py/pyw are seen as file objects

Comment: i already did it also not work :((